# jQuery Off Screen Nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write a simple jquery function to add classes to my html for an offscreen `nav` transition. I can do this easily by using `.toggleClass`, but I want to use an if statement that if the `nav` is out clicking on the body (anything other than the nav) will hide it again.

I've set up a [demo codepen](http://codepen.io/samyerkes/pen/wrjJu). Can anyone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('body !nav')
```

is not a valid selector. What you should do is add a listener to the document:

```
$(document).click(function() {
  // Stuff you want to do on a click
});
```

This will capture all clicks that aren't handled by another function. Then, capture the clicks that happen on nav:

```
$("nav").click(function(e) {
  // Stuff that should happen when nav is clicked.
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things to fix here:

1) Use `stopPropagation()` ([Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)) on the nav click to avoid registering a body click (the event bubbles up by default):

```
$('nav').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

2) Use the `:not` selector ([Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)):

```
$('body:not(nav)').click(function(e) {
    if( $('nav').hasClass('active')){
        $('nav, #wrapper').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

[Updated Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cikde)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('a#menu').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  //this should just be .addClass but to demonstrate functionality I've left it as .toggleClass
  $('nav, #wrapper').toggleClass('active');


});


//how I want it to work

//on click of anything besides nav, if the active class is on the nav, take off the active class
$('body:not(nav)').click(function(e) {

  if( $('nav').hasClass('active')){
    $('nav, #wrapper').removeClass('active');
  }

});
```